# How can I solve "This relative module was not found:" problem? (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, node-modules

When I try to run the application with npm start, I get a following error:

---

This relative module was not found:

- ./src/router/index.js in ./src/main.js

---

And this is my main.js:

```
/ The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './src/router/index.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

And this is my index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Firstpage from "../components/Firstpage.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter ({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: Firstpage
    },
    ]
});
```

Also my node_modules marked with gray color.
I expected this is router problem.
How can I solve this problem?

++

This is my project file structure:
[Project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjnjg.png)

And actually, I have another problem. I can't get my picture from my assets. I already add this code to my component.

Can someone solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your project file structure (i.e. where the files are located relative to each other)?

Comment: If 'main.js' is also in /src, and since your router source file is named 'index.js', try ```import router from './router'```

Comment: @zr0gravity7 I edited my question. Can you check it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use '.' to begin your path, you are telling your relative path is starting from the current directory. So in your case the path to your `router` is obviously wrong. It should be

`import router from './router/index.js'.`

You do not have `src` in your current folder where you have the `main.js`. You are already inside `src`, so you just have to go into the `router`

Your `node_modules` is grayed because that folder is not tracked by your version controlling system (Git). It is configured in the file named `.gitignore` to ignore tracking this folder. You can [read more](https://flaviocopes.com/should-commit-node-modules-git/) whether you should or should not track your `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your node version.install latest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30620172)